# Group XML output based on a hardcoded number using SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, grouping, xquery

I'm having a query which gives output in XML form.

```
DECLARE @XMLDATA1 XML 
SET @XMLDATA1 = (


SELECT StudentId AS 'StudentID',
StudentName AS 'StudentName',
StudentAge AS 'Age',
StudentYear 'Year'

FROM Student 
ORDER BY StudentId
FOR XML PATH('StudentLine')
)

SELECT ( CAST(@XMLDATA1 AS XML ))
FOR XML PATH ('StudentRecords') , Root('Student')
```

And the sample output will be as following.

```
<StudentRecords>
    <Student>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>12</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Kevin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>13</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Peter</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>14</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Martin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>15</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Justin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
    </Student>
</StudentRecords>
```

I want to split these records from `<StudentRecords>` tag based on a hardcoded number inside the sql query. As an example if I want to split to 3 records the xml will be as following.

```
<StudentRecords>
    <Student>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>12</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Kevin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>13</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Peter</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>14</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Martin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
    </Student>
</StudentRecords>
<StudentRecords>
    <Student>
        <StudentLine>
            <StudentID>15</StudentID>
            <StudentName>Justin</StudentName>
            <Age>10</Age>
            <Year>5</Year>
        </StudentLine>
    </Student>
</StudentRecords>
```

There can be scenarios like records with 100000 `<StudentLine>` tags and hardcoded number can be 2000.
Can somebody help me to achieve this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to implement it via XQuery and FLWOR expression.

- Number of rows in a group will be an input parameter.
- We will use `NTILE()` function to create groups based on the number
  of rows in a group.
- FLWOR expression has two loops: (1) iterates through groups, (2) iterates through the `<StudentLine>` elements in a given group.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY, StudentName VARCHAR(30), Age INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (StudentID, StudentName, Age) VALUES
(1,  'Martha',  10),
(2,  'Boris',  12),
(3,  'Judy',  15),
(12, 'Kevin',  19),
(13, 'Peter',  10),
(14, 'Martin', 18),
(15, 'Justin', 25);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- denominator specifies # of rows in a group
DECLARE @NumOfGroups DECIMAL(10,1) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl) / 3.0;
SET @NumOfGroups = CEILING(@NumOfGroups);

-- just to see
SELECT groupId = NTILE(CAST(@NumOfGroups AS INT)) OVER (ORDER BY StudentID)
    , *
FROM @tbl;

SELECT (
    SELECT groupID = NTILE (CAST(@NumOfGroups AS INT)) OVER (ORDER BY StudentID)
        , *
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('StudentLine'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('

    for $gr in distinct-values(/root/StudentLine/groupID/text())
    return <StudentRecords>
                <Student>
            {
                for $x in /root/StudentLine[(groupID/text())[1] eq $gr]
                return $x
            }
        </Student>
    </StudentRecords>

');
```

**Output**

```
  <StudentRecords>
    <Student>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>1</groupID>
        <StudentID>1</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Martha</StudentName>
        <Age>10</Age>
      </StudentLine>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>1</groupID>
        <StudentID>2</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Boris</StudentName>
        <Age>12</Age>
      </StudentLine>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>1</groupID>
        <StudentID>3</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Judy</StudentName>
        <Age>15</Age>
      </StudentLine>
    </Student>
  </StudentRecords>
  <StudentRecords>
    <Student>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>2</groupID>
        <StudentID>12</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Kevin</StudentName>
        <Age>19</Age>
      </StudentLine>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>2</groupID>
        <StudentID>13</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Peter</StudentName>
        <Age>10</Age>
      </StudentLine>
    </Student>
  </StudentRecords>
  <StudentRecords>
    <Student>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>3</groupID>
        <StudentID>14</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Martin</StudentName>
        <Age>18</Age>
      </StudentLine>
      <StudentLine>
        <groupID>3</groupID>
        <StudentID>15</StudentID>
        <StudentName>Justin</StudentName>
        <Age>25</Age>
      </StudentLine>
    </Student>
  </StudentRecords>
```

Comment: Hi @Yitzhak Khabinsky thank you for your answer but there shouldn't be <root> tag in root of the xml. There is no common root tag. Group wise this tag should be common root tag <StudentRecords> for each group.

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon, my answer is producing well-formed XML. If you don't need a well-formed XML, just remove the root tag.

Comment: @RasangaAbeykoon, I updated the answer. There is no root element anymore. It makes the output XML a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me w/o FLWOR

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (StudentID INT PRIMARY KEY, StudentName VARCHAR(30), Age INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (StudentID, StudentName, Age) VALUES
(1,  'Martha',  10),
(2,  'Boris',  12),
(3,  'Judy',  15),
(12, 'Kevin',  19),
(13, 'Peter',  10),
(14, 'Martin', 18),
(15, 'Justin', 25);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- denominator specifies # of rows in a group
DECLARE @NumOfGroups DECIMAL(10,1) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl) / 3.0;
SET @NumOfGroups = CEILING(@NumOfGroups);

-- no FLWOR used
WITH c AS   (
            SELECT groupID = NTILE (CAST(@NumOfGroups AS INT)) OVER (ORDER BY StudentID)
                , *
            FROM @tbl
            )
SELECT      (   SELECT      StudentID, StudentName, Age
                FROM        c
                WHERE       c.groupID = g.groupID
                FOR XML     PATH('StudentLine'), TYPE   ) AS Student
FROM        (
            SELECT DISTINCT groupID FROM c
            ) g
FOR XML     PATH('')
```